# The Pushout in the Category of rings

Tags: ring-theory, category-theory, modules

So i have the following prroposition:

[image]

Can someone explain to me how this object even makes sense? In the definition of the tensor product we take it over a common ground ring R. I guess we could turn a ring A into an A-module just by taking the multiplication map but then we have a different base. Or do we get the structure required through the map from C?

Comment: A map $C\to A$ of commutative rings gives $A$ the structure of a $C$-algebra. Likewise with $B$. Then the tensor product of $C$-algebras is still a $C$-algebra (and in particular, a commutative ring). The notation $\otimes_C$ suggests that we need to be thinking of $A$ and $B$ as algebras over $C$.

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly where i was not sure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By definition of colimit,the pushout is an object $X$ (together with the required arrows $i_A,i_B$) such that
$$\tag1\begin{matrix}C&\stackrel {a}\rightarrow &A\\\downarrow\rlap{\scriptsize b}&&\downarrow\rlap{\scriptsize i_A}\\B&\stackrel{i_B}\rightarrow&X \end{matrix}$$
commutes and for every commuting
$$\tag2\begin{matrix}C&\stackrel {a}\rightarrow &A\\\downarrow\rlap{\scriptsize b}&&\downarrow\rlap{\scriptsize f_A}\\B&\stackrel{f_B}\rightarrow&Y \end{matrix}$$
there exists a unique $h\colon X\to Y$ with $h\circ i_A=f_A$ and $h\circ i_B=f_B$.

---

Note that $X=A\otimes_CB$ with $i_A(a)=a\otimes 1$ and $i_B=1\otimes b$ indeed makes $(1)$ commute (i.e., for $c\in C$, we have $c\otimes 1=1\otimes c$), and that for any $(2)$, we can (and must) define $h(a\otimes b)=f_A(a)f_B(b)$. Thus the tensor product is indeed the pushout.